# Neo4J returns node twice when matched with other node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to get values (2 set of values) from two relationships that have one node in common and then return all sets.

I have tried this code, but for the first set that has only one result it duplicates it because of the second set that has two results.

```
MATCH (sti:SingleTaskInstance) <- [:CONTAINS] - (cti:CollaborativeTaskInstance {cti_id: "RD1CT"}) 
- [:CONTAINS] -> (cti2:CollaborativeTaskInstance) return sti, cti2
```

Here is the result

[image]

We see that **sti** is duplicated while it should only return one result.

I have also tried using collect (distinct sti) on the set I do not want to duplicate but it's still not working. Any suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cypher, you will get rows of results depending on all possible paths that matched the pattern. In your case, two paths were found that matched the pattern, but both of them happen to have the same sti node, which is why you see it appear twice. This is by design. Results are not grouped implicitly, you need to do this yourself using aggregation functions.

If you want to collect cti nodes per distinct sti node, then you'll need to collect() like so:

```
MATCH (sti:SingleTaskInstance) <- [:CONTAINS] - (cti:CollaborativeTaskInstance {cti_id: "RD1CT"}) - [:CONTAINS] -> (cti2:CollaborativeTaskInstance)
RETURN sti, collect(DISTINCT cti2)
```

We are collecting the distinct cti2 nodes just in case a cti2 node is reachable by multiple cti nodes (otherwise it might appear multiple times). When you aggregate, the non-aggregation variables become distinct, so you'll get distinct sti nodes by virtue of the aggregation.

Comment: I understand.Thank you for your answer it's working fine now :)